# Django 1.9: Unable to see uploaded photos

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

I have some **photos uploaded** but I was **unable to see photos** in temeplates

***My template***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
          {% if object.productimage_set.count > 0 %}
        <div>
            {% for img in object.productimage_set.all %}
            {{ img.image.file }}
            {{ img.image.url }}
        <img class='img-responsive' src='{{ img.image.url }}' />
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    <div class="lead">{{ object.description }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

***My model***

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

def __unicode__(self):  # def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/')
```

***Setting for media***

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "my_static"),
    ]
    STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static_root")
    STATIC_URL = '/media/media_root/'
    MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "media_root")
```

***My urls***

```
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
 url(r'^$', views.ProductViewList.as_view(), name='ProductViewList'),
 url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='Product_Detail'),]
```

***My folder structure***

[image]

In the template **{{ img.image.url }}** gives -> **product/mp3.jpg**. But still I'm unable to see the image

The console shows that image is loaded from `http://127.0.0.1:8080/product/1/product/mp3.jpg` I guess there is some prob with the url to collect the image but not sure

Any help is much appreciated....Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the MEDIA_URL to your settings.py, if you haven't.

In your case, the MEDIA_URL should be `media_root`. My Image links all have /media/....jpg.

In addition, you can specify the URLs:

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    # static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Comment: But this is only work in debug mode, when `DEBUG=false` django raise`404 Not found`

Answer (score 2):

Here's some documentation from Django on this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

I prefer keeping my media files separate from my static files, so during development I actually store mine in the project root. The following snippets use the project root as the media location, but you can easily adjust this by changing it to `static/media_root` if you'd prefer to keep your current location.

First make sure you've defined your media root in your settings.py file:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Then try adding the following to your project's urls.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}))
```